# Java EE / jpa /jpql

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

I am trying to improve my skills in Java EE

I try to use this Query which I found it [Here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/path)

```
SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Object e WHERE TYPE(e) <> Country
```

i use it like that

```
TypedQuery<String> query=(TypedQuery<String>) manager.createQuery
( "SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Object e WHERE TYPE(e) <> Country");
List list=query.getResultList();
for(Object entity : list)
System.out.println(entity);
```

but I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: FROM near line 1, column 17 [SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Object e WHERE TYPE(e) <> Country]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1374)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1315)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:280)
```

anyone have an idea how to correct that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your typedQuery is not correct. You shouldn't cast a Query in TypedQuery.

Use

```
  TypedQuery<FooBar> query = em.createQuery(MyQuery, FooBar.class);
```

instead

See http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/api

Comment: thank you 
I do not think it is the source of error because it works with this query 
    "SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Country e"
I think the error is caused by the "Object" clause

Comment: Ofc it is, cause jpa don't understand what Object is doing here, as it's not a declared entity. However if this type of query is possible, i suppose it may fix. Plz let me know the result of your investigations

Comment: hello you are right jpa don't understand the type Object, at first I was thinking that this query would return the number of antities I have in my database (and that was wrong), and it works when I modify the Query like that:
    "SELECT COUNT(u) FROM User u WHERE TYPE(u) <> Client".
and returns the number of Administrators I have in my database 

Client and Administrators are two type inherited from the entity User

Thank you for your interaction with topic

Comment: What does this query do if not counting entities in DB ??  Does TypedQuery<Object>  q = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Object e", Object) work ? or should it be TypedQuery<Foo>  q = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Object e", Foo) to count all Foo records in database ? If so, i suppose that you must use an entity super type to count all entities record using this kind of query. I learned something anyway. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I try this two query  TypedQuery<Object> q = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Object e", Object), TypedQuery<Foo> q = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Object e", Foo). but both didn't work. 
all what I want to know is how the Type clause work?
and I understand that it can be used: for example in this case,  
if you have a table user which is mapped To the entity (User)
 and you have two type of user Client and Admin (Client an Admin two Entity enherited from User) so if you want two know how many Client do you have in your database  you can use the clause Type

Comment: excuse me if I can't explain it fluently I am still trying to learn Jee